# $n^2-n+2$ plane divisions by $n$ circles

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, combinations

Yesterday I learned that there can be at most $n^2-n+2$ plane divisions by $n$ circles.

Can someone help me understand why if I have $k$ circles on the plane, that divide it into $k^2-k+2$ parts, and draw another circle, then the maximum number of divisions it will add is $2k$? I can't seem to comprehend it.

I have seen proofs that just say:"It's obvious that this circle will intersect with each one of the others in at most $2$ points, so we get $2k$ new parts from $k$ circles". The fact that there are $2$ intersections for each circle don't make it obvious to me, that $2k$ new divisions will be added.

Comment: If you know something about planar graphs (especially, Euler's characteristic formula $V-E+F=2$), then I find that students tend to understand more quickly when I offer a graph-theoretic proof, than a proof using a correspondence between intersections and regions.

Comment: @Batominovski I have heard of planar graphs and even know that you can't draw non intersecting lines between all 3 wells and all 3 houses, but I haven't seen V-E+F=2 before, I will read about it though, please post your proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a configuration with the maximum number of regions produced by $n$ circles.  That is, every circle intersects each of the $(n-1)$ other circles in two points and no three circles meet at a single point.  Now, consider the graph $G(V,E)$ where the vertex set $V$ is the set of the intersection points of this configuration, and the edge set $E$ is the set of circular arcs that connect two points in $V$ (without interruption by another intersection).

Now, we shall count $|V|$ and $|E|$.  Note that each circle has $2(n-1)$ intersection points.  There are $n$ circles, and each intersection point belongs to exactly $2$ circles.  Therefore, the number of intersection points is
$$|V|=\frac{1}{2}\,\big(2(n-1)\big)\,n=n(n-1)\,.$$
Now, each vertex in $V$ has degree $4$ (being the intersection of two circular arcs).  Thus, by the Handshaking Lemma, we have
$$\begin{align}|E|&=\frac{1}{2}\,\sum_{v\in V}\,\deg(v)=\frac{1}{2}\,\sum_{v\in V}\,4\\&=\frac{1}{2}\,\big(4|V|\big)=2|V|=2n(n-1)\,.\end{align}$$

To finish the proof, we need a little touch from Euler's formula for planar graphs: $$|V|-|E|+|F|=2\,,$$
where $F$ is the set of regions (i.e., plane divisions) formed by the planar graph.  In this problem, $G$ is planar, so $F$ is well defined, and $|F|$ is the desired answer.  We have
$$\begin{align}|F|&=2+|E|-|V|\\&=2+\big(2n(n-1)\big)-\big(n(n-1)\big)\\&=n^2-n+2\,,\end{align}$$
which is exactly the answer to be proven.

Comment: I'll take a look tomorrow, thank you!

Comment: Thanks, this is an awesome proof. But I have been confused since yesterday about how to prove that if we have k circles, such that every 2 intersect in 2 points and no 3 intersect in one point, and add k+1 circle, it will intersect all the other circles in 2 points, how can I make this obvious to myself?

Comment: My proof above is based on an unproven claim that such a maximal configuration for $n$ circles exists.  However, my idea to prove this claim relies on something else entirely, and not sure how to make it easy.  Do you know Helly's Theorem from convex geometry?

Comment: Alternatively, you may consider a regular $n$-gon which inscribes a circle of radius $1$.  At each of the vertex of the regular $n$-gon, draw a circle of radius $1+\epsilon$ for some very small $\epsilon>0$.  This should guarantee that you obtain a maximal configuration for $n$ circles.

Comment: Sorry, but why does it guarantee that? What are the lengths of that n-gon's sides? Are vertices of the n-gon the centers of our circles? Because you say that we inscribe the circles into the n-gon, but if the vertices are also the centers of circles, doesn't it imply that the circles are no longer inscribed?

Comment: I think you completely misunderstood my construction.  The regular $n$-gon **can be inscribed** into a unit circle, but the unit circle is not one of the $n$ circles I care about.  (Let's just say that the unit circle is not drawn.)  Additionally, I am ***not*** inscribing $n$ circles into the $n$-gon.  I use the vertices of the $n$-gon as the centers of $n$ circles, each having the same radius $1+\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks. And what are the lengths of the n-gon's sides?

Comment: That is not an important piece of information.  It can be calculated from knowing that the $n$-gon is regular, and that it can be inscribed in a unit circle.  This is your exercise, if you want to find out the side length.

Comment: Okay, I get the picture now, there's a regular n-gon that can be inscribed into the unit circle, and its corners serve as centers of circles. I have drawn a few examples and see that every circles touches all the others in exactly 2 points, but still don't understand how to prove it formally.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that you have $k$ circles which divide the plane into at most $k^2 - k + 2$ parts. Add a new circle. Consider intersections of this new circle with old circles. There are at most $2k$ such intersections. These points divide a new circle into at most $2k$ consecutive arcs. Each of these arcs divides at most $1$ old part into $2$ parts. Formally, you can also have more than one (say, $s$) arcs inside some old part. But these arcs are disjoint (except for endpoints) so the old part will be divided into at most $s + 1$ slices --- this means that there will be at most $s$ new parts. In total we can have  at most $2k$ new parts. Thus after adding a new circle we can have at most $k^2 - k + 2 + 2k = (k + 1)^2 - (k + 1) + 2$ parts.

Comment: I think I am starting to understand it, so we have 2k points of intersection, and if we connect them by arcs, ith with i+1st, and nth with 1st, we will get 2k arcs. But how do I know that it's possible to draw such a circle?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something in your question, but there's no need to draw this circle --- it is already drawn (this is a circle which we add)

Comment: But how do you add a circle if not by drawing? Anyhow, suppose we have k circles and we need to draw the k+1th circle, how do I know that it's possible to draw it in such a way, that there will be 2k intersections? Sorry for stupid questions. :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I was not totally precise so just forget what I wrote about drawings. Anyway, a circle can have less than $2k$ intersection, but that's ok --- it just means that less than $2k$ parts will be added.

Comment: I know that less than $2k$ parts can be added, but I am interested to know that it's possible to always reach the $n^2-n+2$ upper bound for any $n$. I think that involves proving that the newly drawn circle does indeed intersect with each other circle in 2 points. How can we prove that it's possible?